# Making an .EXE that executes a batch cmd, and prompts for input at a certain point

Tags: windows, encryption, cmd, batch-processing

I'm using DiskCryptor for the first time and i badly need an .EXE that i can use with a hotkey to execute the mounting of my encrypted partitions.

The encrypted drives are just my data drives/partitions and not my OS partition (Windows 7), and they all share the same encryption. 
My current .exe is just a batch cmd file which mounts all drives and loads a keyfile from a pre-defined location, which is the root of an encrypted USB key, designated J:\

However i would really like to add a password that i have to manually enter without it being stored anywhere in a cache or remembered by any means, but the dcrypt software doesn't seem to have a built in prompt function, a small window or cmd prompt where i can enter my password.

I have a macro hotkey that launches two other hotkeys which  locks the system using Screenblur and unmounts all drives using dccon.exe on an unencrypted partition. And the cmd below which mounts all drives if the encrypted usb drive with the keyfile and dcrypt is inserted into my pc.

J:\dcrypt\dccon.exe" -mountall -kf J:\key -p ""

I would like the .EXE to prompt for input which is to be inserted between the ""
And if possible, if the "J:\key" file is not found, prompt a window that lets me browse to find the correct file manually (preferable a window with only an input field and enter button).

I'm not a programmer, so i'm really looking for help achieving this..
From what i get it's actually extremely simple, and if anyone got the know-how maybe you might be as kind as writing the few lines of code needed for me, and posting the code and how to compile correctly?

Would really appreciate this, many thanks in advance to any kind soul out there!

Kindly
-st0rm

Comment: SO is not the right place to request code to be written for you. It is for questions *about* programming, not posting requirements.

Comment: Well i was asking what the code should be, but ok.. Where would you suggest i ask then?

Comment: Your comment reinforces my point... You're asking for complete code. It would be different if you had already written most of a program and just needed help with one step, but you're asking someone to write the whole program *and* tell you how to compile it. That's not the kind of request SO is intended for. The only suggestion I would have is to pitch it as a project on freelancer.com or some other project contracting site.

Comment: Well, i just stumbled over this website while searching. Pardon me if i my request offends.

Comment: feel free to learn a programming language of your choice, start this as your first project and ask specific questions once you run into a problem ... and you are right about the difficulty of this ... a few lines of code ...

Comment: I know HTML, CSS and a little PHP but that's it. I find it extremely boring tbh, i like doing graphics for a website in photoshop if it comes to it. There are tons of people who are brilliant at this, and i've always been able to find a program that suited my needs until now, since this is so specific.  I heard Ruby is pretty great tho, what would you recommend as a starter language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was in that mood ...

so this is beerware ... feel free to buy me a beer if we ever meet ...

c#

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="path_to_dccon_exe" serializeAs="String">
                <value>J:\dcrypt\dccon.exe</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="parameters_for_dccon_exe" serializeAs="String">
                <value>-mountall -kf J:\key -p "{0}"</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.path_to_dccon_exe, string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.parameters_for_dccon_exe, textBox1.Text));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 10);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "OK";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 12);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(272, 42);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "unsuspicious Application";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

    }
}
```

edit: so ... this is what i wrote ... ok, in addition to throwing 2 controls on a from and arranging them

```
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.path_to_dccon_exe, string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.parameters_for_dccon_exe, textBox1.Text));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I literally believed it was just going to be a few lines of code, talk about being ignorant! This is awesome dude, you're the best. If you're ever in Denmark i'll be sure to buy you a whole case of beer :) I'll give it a go at compiling it tomorrow

Comment: it REALLY is just a few lines of code ... the majority here is IDE generated boiler plate code ... to be precise, everything boils down to the button1_Click method ... the whole rest was generated by visual studio while i was throwing a textbox and a button onto a form ... in the app.config you can modify the path and the parameters / arguments for dccon.exe ... in the parameter string {0} will be replaced by whatever you enter into that textbox